# OpenWeatherMap returns undefined

Tags: javascript, openweathermap

OpenWeatherMap returns undefined.
I think my code is problem (not the API or API key or something). because when I open browser and go to `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=[lon]&lon=[lon]&appid=bc12083e70d2d22298c2df1cec7101d9&units=metric` (Brakets are private data), It returns the data. what's wrong with my code?

here's my code:

```js
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos => {
    const lat = pos.coords.latitude;
    const lon = pos.coords.longitude;
    fetch(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=bc12083e70d2d22298c2df1cec7101d9&units=metric`
  ).then(response => {
     return response.json();
  }).catch(err => {
     console.log(`Error: ${err}`)
  })
});
```

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I suggest not  to embed API keys directly in code

Comment: @SaravananSelvamohan The api key is one from internet. I replaced my api key.

Comment: did you make sure you get the `pos` at all?

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Your fetch callback returns the data, but there is nothing that captures that return.

Comment: Your code is working fine:
https://liveweave.com/b2r2fk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure we passing proper values for lat & lon before calling API request and use appropriate return

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos => {
    let lat = pos.coords.latitude;
    let lon = pos.coords.longitude;
    
fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid={apikey}&units=metric`)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
});
```

Comment: No explanation, the code changed to the point that produces different result than expected.

Comment: What's the diffrence? Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Friend, your API call is correct and it is returning result while `lat` and `lon` are passed to it hard coded. Maybe there is a problem in fetching the value from navigator.

Whenever you have a problem with an API call, I suggest you to use **[Postman](https://www.postman.com/)** software to see if it's working or not.